# windows explorer - watch a directory

Tags: registry, explorer

When Windows Explorer is open, I need that, when a file is dragged in a location 
"D:\xyz\" say, then dragging this file should trigger a procedure (any) to run. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have an application or service running which is monitoring that location for changes and takes the appropriate action.

Comment: This seems to be the relevant reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Comment: You're welcome. I had a bit of trouble finding it some time ago, when I needed this functionality (and I don't feel a hyperlink would warrant its own answer).